# Ignite collocation between caches with different affinity keys

Tags: scala, ignite

Let's say I have two tables in separate Ignite caches, `A` and `B` with the respective keys:

```
case class AKey(
    @(QuerySqlField@field) id: Long,
    @(AffinityKeyMapped@field)
    @(QuerySqlField@field) parentId: Long
)

case class BKey(
    @(AffinityKeyMapped@field)
    @(QuerySqlField@field) aId: Long
)
```

Where `A.parentId` is a self reference to another entry in table `A` and `B.aId` is reference to `A.id`.

If I want all `A` entries with the same `parentId` to be collocated, but I also want all `B` entries to be collocated with the `parentId` of the referenced `A` entry, how would I set up this affinity relationship without including a `parentId` field in `B`? Or is this impossible?

It's not clear to me from Ignite's documentation how Ignite establishes an affinity relationship between tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How Ignite manages affinity collocation

Ignite doesn't really establish any "affinity relationship". All it does is mapping of cache keys to affinity keys. All entries in all caches with the same affinity key are guaranteed to be collocated.

E.g. take caches with the following keys

```
class KeyA { int a1; int a2; @AffinityKeyMapped int affKey; }
class KeyB { int b1; int b2; @AffinityKeyMapped int affKey; }
```

Here we say that `KeyA` and `KeyB` are collocated via `affKey` - when the values of `affKey` match, the entries will be collocated. But in fact Ignite has no knowledge of connection between `KeyA` and `KeyB`, it processes the tables separately. Only the guarantee that the mapping of affinity key to a node is consistent makes this work. In other words, relation between this caches only exists in our heads and it is our responsibility to ensure that the collocation is correct.

## Solution

Finally, on your case. It may be surprising but parentId isn't really a good candidate for affinity key. Say we have three values in A

```
{ id: 1, parentId: 0 }
{ id: 2, parentId: 1 }
{ id: 3, parentId: 2 }
```

Here one could expect all values to be collocated since all of them are referencing each other in the same "chain". But this is a relationship Ignite doesn't know about. All it knows is that there are three different `parentId` values - hence, three different affinity keys and no collocation.

To correctly handle this one has to provide some `groupdId` that is guaranteed to be the same across all values. A natural fit in your case would be the ID of the root element in the "tree". Then the `groupdId` will be the `@AffinityKeyMapped`.

```
{ id: 1, parentId: 0, groupId: 1 }
{ id: 2, parentId: 1, groupId: 1 }
{ id: 3, parentId: 2, groupId: 1 }
```

Unfortunately, the second cache has to refer to the exact same value of affinity key, and there is no way to do so without adding that as a field.

```
{ aId: 2, aGroupId: 1 }
```

Also, although it isn't related directly to the question, make sure that `@AffinityKeyMapped` is a part of the cache **key**, not part of the value - otherwise, it will be ignored.

Comment: So do naming conventions matter at all, or is it just 'any affinity key with value x in any cache is guaranteed to be on the same node'?

Comment: Naming doesn't matter, only the values. Affinity key's value is mapped to a partition number and partition is mapped to a node. The mapping code (in fact, that's the function set in `CacheConfiguration.affinity`) has no idea about the names, caches, etc, and is usually the same for all classes and keys.